# Getting java.io.InvalidClassException: local class incompatible: even with serialVersionUID

Tags: java

A developer declared this in a class which implements `Serializable` interface.

```
XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(namespace = "http://employer.webservicedto.dto.com", name = employerRequestDTO")
public class EmployerRequestDTO implements Serializable{

 private static final long serialVersionUID = -3956940714175091216L;
 // all private instance variables with getters & setters

}
```

and the stacktrace says -

> decodeRequestData - Exception in decodeReqData() : 
>   java.io.InvalidClassException:
>   EmployerRequestDTO; local
>   class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID =
>   -3551130751187195282, local class serialVersionUID = -3956940714175091216

```
/**
     * This method de-serializes user's request-data to return respective DTOs
     */
    public static Object decodeRequestData(String requestData, String userType){
        Object userRequestDTO = null;
        try{    
            byte[] b = Base64.decode(requestData);
            ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
            ObjectInputStream si = new ObjectInputStream(bi);
```

Comment: '@XmlType(namespace = "http://employer.webservicedto.dto.com", name = employerRequestDTO)'

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the class was serialized with the `serialVersionUID` value set to `-3551130751187195282` then the class was updated in source and `serialVersionUID` was set to `-3956940714175091216`. So now the source of the class is not compatible with the version that was serialized.
You can try setting `serialVersionUID` back to `-3551130751187195282` - but i would be careful with that. Try to find out why this value was changed - maybe there where other changes in the class source which makes it not possible to use with previously serialized versions.

Comment: Thanks, this was my issue. I had assumed that re-serializing with a "new" singleton (which was my error recovery) would have fixed it, but I had to explicitly delete the existing file.